# Wheel slippage when accelerating from stop

Tags: troubleshooting, hybrid

I drive a 2018 Ford Fusion Energi. I've noticed that occasionally when accelerating from stop, my wheels slip a little. My tires don't have a lot of wear on them, so I don't think it's a traction issue. (I've also never had any issues stopping.) I've tried disabling traction control and that doesn't seem to solve the problem. I'm assuming there's probably something going on with the transmission.

I won't be trying to fix anything myself, but I'd like to hear some objective opinions of what might be going on before I decide whether to get it serviced.

EDIT

Found this quote from 2017 Car and Driver

> The low-rolling-resistance tires prioritize fuel economy over grip, so sharp maneuvers prompt a fair bit of squeal followed by urgent intervention from the stability-control system. Driven more calmly, both the steering and the brakes offer wonderfully natural feel.

In consulting the owner's manual, the stability control is separate from the traction control and cannot be turned off. I wonder if that might be where the issue lies.

Comment: Do you mean that your wheels slip on the road surface? Do you hear rubber squealing? Referencing the transmission implies that power applied from the engine isn't getting to the tires. Which of the two options is more accurate?

Comment: Automatic or manual transmission?

Comment: @jwh20 Automatic (CVT)

Comment: @fred_dot_u Good point. I do hear some squealing so I guess maybe the transmission doesn't make sense. But I've only got 23,000 miles on the vehicle, I use snow tires for a good portion of the year, there are no obvious signs of wear, and I have no issues braking to suggest that the tires are at fault.

Comment: Some tires has poor traction even with full tread. My present set are bad . The first few time I looked around to see who was spinning tires. ( 2011 Murano , so not exactly a hot-rod). I never used this brand tire before but I expect it may be against the rules to name a poor product.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Fair enough. It seems to happen randomly though with no difference on wet or dry roads. They're still the tires that came with the vehicle, can't remember the brand.

Comment: So is it the tires/wheels slipping (seems unlikely to me) or the CVT belt slipping and making a noise?  CVTs are notoriously unreliable and it may be the cause of your problem.  If the belt slips it will be noticeable about the same as a wheel slipping and the metal-on-metal noise is a scratchy/squeeky sound.

Comment: @jwh20 It sounds like the tires are slipping, but I've never had someone be able to observe from outside the vehicle to confirm.

Comment: But you've said the tires are in good shape and this happens on dry pavement.  Does this car really have so much power that you can regularly and inadvertently spin the tires when starting out??

Comment: If this is under Ford's 3 yr/36k basic,  5 yr/60k mile power train warranty, schedule an appointment. Second guessing from anyone should not be a priority to warranty coverage against manufacturing defects. Tried enquiring on Ford Fusion forums where there may be others with similar issues to share?

Comment: @FDryer Good point. I *just* got past the 3 yr mark but might be worth taking it in anyway.

Comment: If this is related to power train issues then your 5 yr/60k mile warranty should cover it unless you surpassed 60k miles